# Why is it "for me to buy it" rather than "for me to bought it"? What is the reason we use the infinitive?

Tags: past-tense, infinitives

Looking at the sentence:

"for me to buy this flat it needed to be furnished"

What is the grammatical reason for using "to buy" and not "bought" even though it refers to a past action?

Comment: Where did you see this sentence? "For me to have bought this flat it needed to be furnished" or "For me to buy this flat it needs to be furnished" seem more natural to me. On the other hand the speaker might say refuse to buy it now because of something that was or wasn't done in the past: "I want to buy this flat now, but I can't because nobody connected it to the water supply".

Comment: The "to" is part of the infinitve verb, which is "buy", not "bought".

Comment: Sorry I realised that I remembered the sentence wrongly. It was "there were two conditions for me to buy this apartment". Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of examples of past conditional, which would place everything in the past tense. But past conditional tense is used in two ways - to talk about things you would *normally* do in the past (eg '*I would buy flats if they were furnished*'), or to express what you would have done (but didn't) if certain conditions had been met (eg '*I would have bought the flat if it had been furnished*').

Neither of these applies to your quotation. It is neither talking about a regular event, nor a hypothetical event that didn't happen. It sounds like the person *did* buy the flat, and is just laying out a condition that was met in order for them to do so. Saying "*for to have bought this flat it needed to be furnished*" would sound like they didn't buy the flat because it wasn't furnished because, even though 'have bought' is in the past tense, it would only be hypothetical and not something that actually happened.

Comment: Sorry I realised that I remembered the sentence wrongly. It was "there were two conditions for me to buy this apartment". Is that correct?